# create a hash function from scratch in python using list

Tags: python, hash

**Hi
I am a beginner in python and would be really useful if someone help me to write a class for hash in python to perform some functions.**

I got this code from https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-create-a-hash-table-from-scratch-in-python/
still some iter() functions are missing and need help

Comment: We will not write functions for you, but we may help you explaining problems you have on implementing your functions. But we need to know what are your problems. What do you not understand on solving the problem?

Comment: while looping through the hash class it is giving an error "TypeError: 'HashTable' object is not iterable
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ask myself:

- How does the hash list look like with many values in it?
- What should the return look like?

The hash list can be a list of list of lists as your link implemented it. Now the `__iter__(self)` method should yield one value after another. The return may be a list containing two values.

So, it is a traversing problem. To start with some code you can implement in python:

```
my_list = [[['key4', 4]], None, [['key1', 1], ['key2', 2]], None, 
          [['key0', 0]], None, None, [['key3', 3]]]

def traverse(my_list=None):
    if isinstance(my_list, (list, tuple)):
        for value in my_list:
            for subvalue in traverse(value):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield my_list

print(list(traverse(my_list)))
```

But this one does not solve your problem: you may need to add two more conditions for the correct termination condition:

- a test for the list length in the first place and
- a test if the value in my_list is a list and if the first element of this value is also list ( to traverse down the tree )

Comment: Thank you...I will try with this concept